# reroute everything but one port to oher server with iptables

Tags: iptables

I have moved to a new webserver and now I redirect all traffic to the new server with

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#clear old rules:
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
#masquerade and redirect everything:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
```

which works fine, until all DNS entries are widespread. But now I cannot log in into the old mashine any more.

How can I keep open an SSH port on the old server 1.1.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iptables, the first matching rule wins. So the correct ordering of the rules is important.

In this case, the rule that says what to do to traffic of port 22 must come *before* the rule that says what to do to "everything else". And while RETURN would work if the chain's policy is unchanged from the default, it might be clearer to be explicit and just use ACCEPT as a synonym of "just process this as normal":

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: But Be careful!!! I did this on my old server, forwarded everything to the new server, which lead to a vulnerable open-relay email host on the new server. I am still trying to understand why this was the result, but you should also not rerout the email ports to the new server as well